# VB.NET SQLClient Table Names are ambiguous

Tags: vb.net

Here is some simple sample code that demonstrates how I am getting results back from SQL Server:

```
Dim dtbTable As System.Data.DataTable
Dim sdaDataAdapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
sdaDataAdapter = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM A; SELECT * FROM B", Connection)

dtbTable = New System.Data.DataTable()
dtbTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
sdaDataAdapter.Fill(dtbTable)

sdaDataAdapter = Nothing
objCommandBuilder = Nothing
```

In .Net, table A will come out TABLE and Table B will come out TABLE1... I want them to hold their real table names.

How do I get the real table names of the tables that come in from the SQL Query ?  All the column names are correct, but the tables come out TABLE, TABLE1, TABLE2...  I obviously know how to set them in my code or parse the table names and set them in code...  I am wondering why .Net looses the table names in the first place and if there is a way for them to not be turned into ambiguous names.

Why would the writers of the SQLClient drivers not think we care about table names?

Any ideas from anyone on a way to get around this without having to set Table Name manually?

Comment: "<Answer to SQL question here>"

Comment: Could you show the complex sql? It'll possibly help with answering why the naming changed.

Comment: It would be nice if the table names held on any SQL that I run...  .Net will transform every table with a table name like  TABLE, TABLE1, TABLE2...

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches - map the tables to `DataTables` and load the `DataSet` one table at a time w/desired name.

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(OISConnectString)
    Connection.Open()
    Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FIS..FIS_Log; SELECT * FROM FIS..FIS_Log_CA", Connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)

    Debug.Print(ds.Tables(0).TableName) ' Table
    Debug.Print(ds.Tables(1).TableName) ' Table1

    Dim dtLog As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim dtLog_CA As DataTable = ds.Tables(1)

    ' work with DataTables by name

    Stop
    'reset
    ds = Nothing
    da = Nothing

    ds = New DataSet()

    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FIS..FIS_Log", Connection)
    da.Fill(ds, "FIS_Log")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FIS..FIS_Log_CA", Connection)
    da.Fill(ds, "FIS_Log_CA")

    Debug.Print(ds.Tables(0).TableName) ' Table
    Debug.Print(ds.Tables(1).TableName) ' Table1

    dtLog = ds.Tables("FIS_Log")
    dtLog_CA = ds.Tables("FIS_Log")

    Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

You might find TableAdapterManager useful depending on your platforms

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but both of those approaches are not generic enough...  I was hoping there was a way that .Net could figure out the real table names... like it does for column names.  It does not name columns Column1. Column2, Column3   ... it knows the real names.  Why does it not know the real names of the tables?   Maybe TableAdapterManager  might be more intelligent... haven't worked enough with that.   Thanks!

Comment: Queries don't necessarily have table names - the query itself results in a table. e.g. you can build a query to join several tables together - what would you expect ADO.Net to return? You are building the SQL, why don't you know the "table name?"

Comment: I can... I was just hoping if a query had a primary table name, ADO could resolve it.  It does not even try.  Even if there were 10 joins, it could just the primary FROM <table> as the table name.   I guess I will just keep naming it the way I have been doing it for years...

Comment: In t he code above (second half) I don't know if reusing the DataAdapter is a problem or not. Might be a problem for updates.